# Datepicker is showing something else at the place of month and days

Tags: javafx

This is the JavaFX Datepicker Control.

When I run the program, it is showing something else in the date picker, as you can see in the picture:

[image]

I am not getting what is the exact problem.

Comment: I think your problem would be easier to solve if you provided more information. For example: Locale, OS, Java version.

Comment: Java : jdk1.8.0_121, OS : Windows 7

Comment: Can you provide  a [mcve] for the question, to see exactly how did you used it?

Comment: actually, there is no problem in the code. it works perfectly on windows 8(machine 1) but the same project with window 7(machine 2) shows the above Datepicker.

Comment: The problem most likely is that, the answer is showing.

Comment: Maybe the [`chronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html#chronologyProperty) is set to some exotic chronology type. Try explicitly setting [`IsoChronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/IsoChronology.html) as `chronology`.

Comment: @Tyson: It's better to edit your question and add the new information. In that way readers don't have to browse though the comments to see it.